# How to align Salutation and First Name side by side Like Standard Page in VF Page?

Tags: visualforce

I am overriding Standard Person Account "New Button" page with VF Page. this is the vf code in side page block section

```
`<apex:inputField value="{!contact.salutation}" /> 
<apex:inputField value="{!contact.firstname}"/>`
```

now how to align these two fields together like in standard page ?

I am getting  output like this for First Name // Rest Of code Is there in VF page which i have removed in IMAGE//  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pageblockSectionItem to group them together

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
<apex:outputpanel >
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.Salutation}" />
    &nbsp;
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: I already tried <apex:pageblockSectionItem> ,If i use it "First Name " will be disappeared, Then I have to use <apex:outputpanel> to put "First Name". Is there any another way ?

Comment: Updated my code sample the way that I do it.

Comment: I have uploaded the error image in question

Comment: Sorry, Typing the code in the message, going too fast. Should have had "inputfields" not "outputfields". Try the new version.

Comment: Ya, sorry even I figured it out but didn't update here